# Camera index out of range

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)
```

i've been receiving some error can y'all teach me how to fix this

```
[ERROR:0@0.076] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 cv::obsensor::getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
```

Comment: That says you don't have two video sources.  Remember that it counts starting from 0, so "1" is "the second camera".

Comment: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

Comment: so if i leave it blank it uses whatever is available? cap = cv2.VideoCapture()

Comment: No, it is not. You should specify the video source. for example, 0 is your webcam in your laptop, if you connect a second USB camera it will have index 1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm setting the index for cv2.VideoCapture, I'll usually do in terminal:

```
ll /dev/video*
```

to list the available camera devices, example output:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jan 26 21:13 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Jan 26 21:13 /dev/video1
```

Then just keep trying each number after `video` until I find one that works. If that command doesn't give an output, that could be a sign that something is wrong with the camera you're trying to use. I found out that plugging my camera device into a USB 2.0 was working, and 3.0 wasn't, turned out the cable I was using wasn't compatible with USB 3.0.